# Recursive Struct in C++

Tags: c++

I found the following code and it seems working but I can not understand it at all.
It looks like a *Recursive Struct* but I never saw this before.

```
template<int B, int N>
struct Pow {
    enum{ value = B*Pow<B, N-1>::value };
};

template< int B >
struct Pow<B, 0> {
    enum{ value = 1 };
};
int quartic_of_three = Pow<3, 4>::value;
```

any idea what is this?

Comment: It uses compile-time recursion to compute B to the power of N.

Comment: Very basic template metaprogramming - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's a way to compute an integral power at compile time, relying on the compiler supporting the requisite number of template specializations (i.e., it's not exactly portable code)

read up on templates in your favorite c++ text book

if you don't have a c++ text book yet: you need it, take a look in the SO FAQ **[C++ book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)**

---

a much better and (in a few years) probably much more portable way in C++11 is to use a `constexpr` function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

constexpr int constpow( int base, int n )
{
    return (n == 0? 1 : base*constpow( base, n - 1 ));
}

int main()
{
    int const quarticOfThree = constpow( 3, 4 );
    wcout << quarticOfThree << endl;
}
```

however, that's not supported by visual c++ 11.0, the latest version of visual c++ as i write this

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not exactly portable code"? I believe it's fully standard-compliant.

Comment: @AndreiTita: you quote a conclusion (that's the meaning of "i.e.") of a sentence with a premise. the other premise is that different compilers have different limits. so, it's standard-compliant non-portable code.

Comment: Template recursion depth can be unreasonably short by the standard @andreitita

Comment: `constexpr` is much less portable than templates are at this point.

Comment: @Yakk C++03 recommends at least 17 but C++11 increases it to 1024, while only recommending to allow at least 512 nested `constexpr` evaluations. It's sort of academic; the only real rule is to give your compiler a metaprogram that completes in a reasonable amount of time. Compilers have these limits to cause a message to be printed, so the user doesn't wait all day for a result or get a segfault. As for compliance, the Standard just isn't making an effort to legislate metaprogam complexity.

Answer (score 2):

The important things to note in this template definition are:

- the template parameters are *values*, and not types as many people usually expect in templates;
- the field `value` of the struct template is computed from these parameters;
- the template has a partial specialization for the second parameter `N` when set with `0`.

As you noticed, the template recurse on the `value` field computation. that recursion would be infinite, if the partial specialization were not defined. When the second parameter "reaches" `0`, ie. when, by following the nesting of template instantiation in the attempt of getting the successive value fields necessary to compute the outermost one, the compiler finally needs to instantiate the template with parameter N equal to `0`, and selects the partial specialization version, which contains a constant value of `1` for the field. Then the compiler can compute each nested value field, to finally return to the outermost one.

Using this technique, it is possible to have the compiler compute certain values offline (ie. at compile time). This let the programmer have his constant values defined by their parameters and formula, rather than having to hardcode them, or make the compiled program compute them at each run.

But the issue with this approach, how clever it may seem, is its readability and thus ease of maintenance. That's most probably the reason why the new standard offers the `constexpr` concept, which is a much proper way to define so called [pure computation](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

---

It should be noted that both fields of the templates are signed, and that the computation does not try to handle the negative values in any way. If N is initially set at `-1`, the result could be interesting.